# My ComboBox SelectionChangedEvent sends the previously selected Item

Tags: c#, wpf

So, whenever I change the selections I need to call a method, that compares the new selection with different options. Problem is, that it always sends the object selected before that

Initially I thought I could just invert the selection, but that would only work with 2 options.

```
// Create the Combobox
ComboBox selectType = new ComboBox();
selectType.Text = "Select Type";
selectType.SelectionChanged += CallChange;

ComboBoxItem sortingAlgorithm = new ComboBoxItem();
sortingAlgorithm.Content = "Sorting Algorithm";

ComboBoxItem searchingAlgorithm = new ComboBoxItem();
searchingAlgorithm.Content = "Searching Algorithm";

// add the items to ComboBox

// Call on new selection
void CallChange(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs args)
{
   _controller.ChangeType((string)selectType.SelectionBoxItem);
}
```

I'd think that it just sends the new selection. Do I have any thinking mistakes or did I mix anything up? Also I know that using Strings to compare selections is very bad practice, I am currently changing it all to dictionaries

Comment: Instead of using an event, why not use databinding?

Answer (score 1):

The selected item is only propagated after the changed event was handled. This allows to manipulate the selected value before it is visible as selected. Therefore the moment the `SelectionChanged` event occurred, the `SelectionBoxItem` hasn't changed yet. You have to reference the selected item from the `args` object instead:

```
// Call on new selection
void CallChange(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs args)
{
  _controller.ChangeType(args.AddedItems.OfType<string>().FirstOrDefault() ?? string.Empty);
}
```

Comment: I just tried this, I am not really sure what args is so I just replaced mine with ^ this, but now I am returning null. Is there something else I need to change?

Comment: `args` is the parameter of the `SelectionChanged` event handler `CallChange(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs args)`. It's your own method.

Comment: Just copy&paste the method and replace your previous version.

Comment: Did, and it will give me a 'System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.''

Comment: Okay at which line? This line: `_controller.ChangeType(args.AddedItems.OfType<string>().FirstOrDefault());`? Or inside `_controller.ChangeTape()`?

Comment: In the controller Method 'CallChange', when I compare it with strings

Comment: I updated the code to use the null-coalescing operator. This should fix it.

Comment: Now the returned String is empty

Comment: Of course it is. This means the selected value is not a string. What is the type you are binding the `ItemsSource` to?